# Current URL in ASPCore Middleware?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there a way I can access the current Requested URL in ASPCore 2.0 Middleware?

Is there something I can Inject?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HttpContext object will be passed to the `Invoke` method of your middleware. You can access the `Request` property on that.

You can use the `GetDisplayUrl` extension method or `GetEncodedUrl` extension method.

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var url1 =context.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
    var url2  = context.Request.GetEncodedUrl();       


    // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
    return this._next(context);
}
```

These 2 extension methods are defined in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` namespace. So make sure you have a using statement to include the namespace

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
```

Comment: Hi, where do I create this Invoke and how do I call it?

Comment: It should be in your middleware. You do not need to call it explicitly. the middleware will be called by the incoming request.

Comment: That is registering the middleware to the pipeline. It will be executed when a request comes in.

Answer (score 2):

Your middleware get `HttpContext context` which has

```
//
// Summary:
//     /// Gets the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest object for this request. ///
public abstract HttpRequest Request { get; }
```

So you may get all needed info in next way:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    //context.Request.Path
    //context.Request.QueryString
    ...

    await next.Invoke();

});
```

Comment: Where do you write this and how to call it?