# Get Current URL as soon as available program.cs / startup.cs in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

Goal:  To GET the URL in browser ASAP on running the ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web application.

What I tried was nearly every sort of hackery inside of `Startup.cs` , which sure you can use DI for registering the `IHttpContextAccessor` to get access to `HttpContext`

Some people will say to use

```
var url = HttpContext?.Request?.GetDisplayUrl();
```

You can use this in a Controller, but if you go to definition you see that the HttpContext is coming from the ControllerBase of Mvc etc..

Seems to be several postings about this and no solutions.

1. I am seeing to build middleware - great, but I don't know how to really do that
2. I seen an article about middleware and call the `Invoke` Method,  but How and Where etc..?   [Current URL in ASPCore Middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572798/current-url-in-aspcore-middleware)
3. Seems like I just want what I had in global.asax in "classic" .net with the URL etc..

I see that Program calls Startup.cs with the `.UseStartup<Startup>();`
Is it possible to get access to be able to END GOAL to get the URL like  `http://localhost:4444`

All I want ...

```
var url = HttpContext?.Request?.GetDisplayUrl();
```

to show my URL as soon as .net core in a class library / startup / program.cs will let me see URL like `http://localhost:4444`

Comment: What you're asking for fundamentally doesn't make any sense.  The *WebHost* simply replies to requests.  It could reply the same values to **any domain**, unless you specify this specifically in your code.  It's like asking a car sales person what car they are going to sell next... how would they know until someone asks them about a specific car?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For handing request, you could try [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

A simple middleware like below:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        //rest code

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Use((context,next) =>
            {
                var url = context.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
                return next.Invoke();
            });

            //rest code
        }
    }
```

For using `GetDisplayUrl()`, add

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
```

Comment: Well actually if I use the code above and put a breakpoint on app.Use and F11 , it never goes inside ,  I gather I need to write a class with a invoke method ?

Answer (score 0):

I had some success using app.UseWhen to conditionally load Middleware based on URL.... example code:

```
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.GetDisplayUrl().Contains("localhost"), appBuilder =>
{
    //conditionally load Middleware based on the URL - e.g change the 500 page
    appBuilder.UseExceptionHandler("/500-local.html");
});
```